# How to store the method parameter values directly to the array list and then pass it to the another method

Tags: java, arraylist

Following is the workflow:

```
Class A{

    B obj_b = new B;

    String x= "abc";
    String y= "def";

    public void method_a(){
        obj_b.method_b(x,y);
    }  
}

Class B{

    C obj_c = new C;
    public String method_b(String Fname, String Lname){

        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        names.add(Fname);
        names.add(Lname);

        String qwerty=("Hello"+ obj_c.method_c(names));

    }
}

Class C{

    public String method_c(ArrayList<String> allElements){
        String xyz = MessageFormat.format(allElements.get(0),allElements.get(1));
        return xyz;
    }
}
```

What I want to do is:

1. In Class B, to add all the arguments directly to the ArrayList(i.e. Fname and Lname to names array list). Number of arguments may vary.There might be some other method calling method_b() with 3 or 4 arguments, that is why I am using ArrayList.
2. Then in Class C, putting each element of the array list(i.e. names) in the method,message(),with comma separated.

Please suggest if any better approach can be taken.

Comment: `al.add(Fname);` -- what is `al`? Please post code that can be compiled, this is not valid Java code as `al` is not declared anywhere.

Comment: @JimGarrison-Sorry, I have edited the code now.

Comment: Your `method_c` is ignoring all but the first 2 elements in the `ArrayList`.

Comment: @DM-Yes! this is what I want to know. Right now I know that I have two arguments so I hard coded it. But what if there are many. How to do that?How to put all the elements separated by a comma.

Comment: @isaace I have edited the code. My bad

Comment: maybe you can pass into format allElements.toArray()

Comment: @DBhatnagar Isn't your arraylist supposed to be an instance variable for class B instead of being a local variable? Right now, the arraylist in class B is not doing anything.

Comment: @user3437460 That array list is being passed here. String qwerty=("Hello"+ obj_c.method_c(names));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think you need something like this:**

```
class B {
    C obj_c = new C();

    public void method_b(String... args) {
        List<String> names = Arrays.asList(args);
        String qwerty = "Hello " + obj_c.method_c(names);
    }
}
```

That way, you can send unlimited args to method_b.

**Hope this helps!**